# How to exclude occurence of a certain date in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

I have a postgres table which has a content like below

```
    date    |   metric    |    device     |         mse         
------------+-------------+---------------+---------------------
 2018-04-02 | cpu         | 10.17.100.1   |    10.8353316326531
 2018-04-03 | cpu         | 10.17.100.1   |    1.84977070342026
 2018-04-04 | cpu         | 10.17.100.1   |    6.94701678240741
 2018-04-05 | cpu         | 10.17.100.1   |    8.38619212962963
 2018-04-06 | cpu         | 10.17.100.1   |      2.468402069161
 2018-04-07 | cpu         | 10.17.102.1   |    7.38240908709163
 2018-04-08 | cpu         | 10.17.102.1   |    11.7493083375325
 2018-04-02 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |    3.12962962962963
 2018-04-03 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |    6.25925925925926
 2018-04-04 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |     3.5697337962963
 2018-04-05 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |   0.440104166666667
 2018-04-06 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |                   0
 2018-04-07 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |    28.1666666666667
 2018-04-08 | mem         | 10.17.102.1   |    28.1666666666667
 2018-04-02 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |    0.25067507558579
 2018-04-03 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.240537426776266
 2018-04-04 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.137486181972789
 2018-04-05 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.325178394274376
 2018-04-06 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.227994614512472
 2018-04-07 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.231201367892836
 2018-04-08 | sap_drops   | 10.17.102.1   |   0.190689097012262
```

As you can see there are several instances of the date `2018-04-08` in the table.What I want is to remove every occurence of `2018-04-08` in the table and leave the rest as it is.

Below is the structure of the table

```
                              Table "public.device_mse"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 date   | date                   |           | plain    |              | 
 metric | character varying(255) |           | extended |              | 
 device | character varying(255) |           | extended |              | 
 mse    | double precision       |           | plain    |              |
```

Based on the answer provided in this question [Exclude day from Pandas Dataframe date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734417/exclude-day-from-pandas-dataframe-date-range), I tried doing something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="metrics", user="souvik", password="********", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
df = psql.read_sql("Select * from device_mse", conn)
df2 = df["date" != datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-04-08', '%Y-%m-%d').date()]
print(df2)
```

But I get an error like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/utorapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/PycharmProjects/Pandas/compare_stats20.py", line 46, in <module>
    df2 = df["date" != datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-04-08', '%Y-%m-%d').date()]
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3843, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/home/souvik/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
df = df[df.date != '2018-04-08']
```

Comment: wha type are the elements of the column `date`?

Comment: hey I found my error.I had set date as an index.By the way the date has a date type.

Comment: Ok, Good job :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my date was set as an index because of which I was getting a key error.After removing the index, now it works fine!